# What would $\log_{24} 48$ be in terms of $x$ if $\log_{12} 36= x$?

Tags: logarithms

What would $\log_{24} 48$ be in terms of $x$ if $\log_{12} 36= x$? 
Which properties to use and how to proceed, please let me know.

Comment: I"m sorry i'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: It's just a simple question and I'm trying to ask what would a term of log be in terms of x which is itself related to some other logarathmic term. 

Comment: so you mean $a*x=log_{24}48$, where you search a?

Comment: Kind of! Please read the question above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the ratio of $\frac{log(3)}{log(2)}$ from $x$. It's given $x=\frac{log(36)}{log(12)}=\frac{2log(3)+2log(2)}{log(3)+2log(2)}$ . SO from here, $\frac{log(3)}{log(2)}=\frac{2x-2}{2-x}$

Now $y=\frac{log(48)}{log(24)}=\frac{4log(2)+log(3)}{3log(2)+log(3)}=\frac{4(2-x)+2x-2}{3(2-x)+2x-2}$

So from here $$y=\frac{6-2x}{4-x}$$
which is the final answer

Hope this will be helpful !

Comment: How did you get $\frac{2x-2}{2-x}$?

Comment: Divide numerator and denominator by $log(2)$ and assume $\frac{log(3)}{log(2)}=\alpha$ and solve for $\alpha$. Equation will become $\frac{2\alpha +2}{\alpha +2}=x$ or else you can use componendo and dividendo. Any one you like !

Comment: Okay you need to make some corrections on that part in your answer. But thanks and could you please tell how did you know that you have to solve it using log2 and log3?

Comment: No, there is no corrections. Solve for $\alpha$ from above equation and put it in $y=\frac{4+\alpha}{3+\alpha}$ where $y=\frac{log(48)}{log(24)}$ . And because every number involved in this question has a factor $2$ and $3$ only. So that's why i used log2 and log3.